# Query: Bulkify Apex Methods Using Collections In Methods

Tags: apex, code-coverage

can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
public static void mobiFormRecordDtlsUpdate(sObject tplan){

    try{
        sObject updateDtls = tplan;
        if(!string.ISBLANK(tplan.Id) && (tplan != null)) {
            update updateDtls;
        }else if (tplan!= null){ 
            insert updateDtls;
      }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error,ex.getMessage());
        ApexPages.addMessage(msg);  

    }

}
```

Comment: How often/where do you call this method?

Comment: Nothing at all wrong with it except you can get rid of most of the code in the try block by using single upsert after checking if not null

Comment: It should not be called within a for loop.

Comment: This method is in helper class. whenever am saving/updating this method is called and this method is called from two vf pages. so you guys give me a solution, it would be helpful :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code seems alright.

So, to answer your question on bulkification of the code. You can do some changes to pass the parameter as a List and perform the operation.

Two ways you can do is are as follows:

> Using Database.upsert with allorNone flag as false, which will ensure
>   the remainder of the DML operation can still succeed even if any one
>   of the record fails.Below is the sample code

```
public static void mobiFormRecordDtlsUpdate(List<sObject> tplanList){
    Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.update(tplanList,false);
    for (Integer i =0; i < tplanList.size(); i++)
    if (!srList[i].isSuccess() {
      // log the error somewhere for later admin action - typically to a persistent sobj
    }
}
```

> Using Database.upsert with allorNone flag as true, wherein exception is thrown if the method is not successful. Sample code below

```
public static void mobiFormRecordDtlsUpdate(List<sObject> tplanList){
    try{
            Database.upsert(tplanList,true); //You can skip passing the 2nd argument as 'true'. As default is true.
    }catch (Exception e) {
        ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error,ex.getMessage());
        ApexPages.addMessage(msg);  
    }
}
```

Now you can call the method by adding it in the sObject List

```
List<sObject> tplanList = new List<sObject>();
//Add all the sObjects after doing a null check
//Call the method
ClassName.mobiFormRecordDtlsUpdate(tplanList);
```